# Oracle sql referencing

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

Can, for example,

table1.columnA reference table2.columnA

if table2.columnA is not a primary key? Or is referencing strictly for primary keys?

Answer (score 3):

There must be a unique constraint on `table2.columnA` in order to reference it in a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.  But it need not be the primary key.